# How do I create a mailbox in powershell and determine which mailstore it creates it in?

Tags: powershell, exchange, mailbox

I need to edit a powershell script that creates new users and add a section that creates them a mailbox, problem I am having is that I need it to check the first letter of the username to determine whether it creates it in 'Store A-M' or 'Store A-Z' databases.  From what I can tell I can import exchange module into powershell (I won't be in exchange shell) and use the enable-mailbox cmdlet, just having problems trying it all in . Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I am running exchange 2010 ona 2008R2 box, but will more than likely run the script from a 2012 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

I use these commands to create a session and import the module, so that I don't have to use EMS:

```
New-PSSession -Name Exchange -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://exchangeserver.domain.com/powershell/ -AllowRedirection -Authentication Kerberos
Import-Module (Import-PSSession (Get-PSSession -Name Exchange)) -Global
```

Once you have the modules imported, you can enable a mailbox like so (assuming you have your user's details already):

```
$mailstore = ""
if($user.Surname[0] -le 'M')
    { $mailstore = "Store A-M" }
else
    { $mailstore = "Store N-Z" }

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $user.samAccountName -Database $mailstore
```

I haven't added all the parameters you might want for the `Enable-Mailbox` command, as there are potentially lots of them and they aren't relevant to the question. You can [see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa998251(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more info.